# Send byte array to iOS app from Java app (with quickserver)

Tags: java, ios, tcp, arrays

I have a byte array in Java. The values are both positive and negative (since they are greater than 127 in the original unsigned array). Now I want to send this array with Quickserver (http://www.quickserver.org/) to my TCP client in an iOS application I am writing as well. I pass the byte array to sendClientBinary() method which accepts the byte array as its input. However, when I receive the array in the iOS client app, all the negative values seem to have been converted to some kind of complement form and mainly into two-byte values: -71 (0xB9) in Netbeans looks in Xcode memory view as 0xC2 0xB9 and -67 (0xBD) in Netbeans appears as 0xC2 0xBD in Xcode. 
Can anyone please provide explanation for this?

I am also able to convert my byte array to char array and masking out all the upper bytes, so now the char array holds the correct values in the full 0-255 range, however, there is no way how to pass a char array to sendClientBinary() method that only accepts byte array as input. 
Should I try to be casting or converting char array to byte array somehow again?

```
//Some code in Java:
//reading my byte array from a method and converting it to char array (sorry if it's not the most efficient way, just need something simple right now
byte byteArray[] = (byte[])functionReturningByteArray();
char charArray[] = new char[byteArray.length];
for (int ij = 0; ij < byteArray.length; ij++)
{
    charArray[ij] = (char) byteArray[ij];
    if (charArray[ij] > 255)
        charArray[ij] &= 0xFF;
}
//and the code sending the data over TCP socket (via Quickserver):
clientH.setDataMode(DataMode.BINARY, DataType.OUT);
clientH.sendClientBinary(byteArray);
//--this is received in iOS as 16-bit values with some prefix such as 0xC2 or 0xC3 for negative  values, if not for the prefix the value would be correct


//or an attempt to send the charArray:
clientH.setDataMode(DataMode.byte, DataType.OUT);
clientH.sendClientBytes(charArray.toString());
//--this doesn't resemble my bytes once received in iOS at all

//iOS reception code:
case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
{
    if(stream == inputStream)
    {
        int len = 0;
        len = [inputStream read:receptionBuf maxLength:2048*2048*2];
        packetBytesReceived += len;
        [packetData appendBytes:receptionBuf  length:len];

        NSString* fullData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:packetData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
...
...
```

I think the problem might be in NSASCIIStringEncoding since I am receiving characters in the main part of my data packet, but some content is just byte data values and this probably could be the cause...? Will start working on it.

Comment: Please post some code.  Especially the code on the receiver side.

Answer (score 0):

0xc2 is the prepend for byte in UTF-8 encoding. It denotes that you are sending a special character in UTF-8 in the 0xc2 sequence. So 0xC2 0xB9 would translate to a superscript character; in particular ^1. My guess (since I assume this is not what you are actually sending) is that your encoding is set incorrectly some place.

Comment: Some of the values have prefix 0xC3 depending on the number that is being transmitted (I think greater values starting around 180 have 0xC3 prefix), however, in my iOS app I am receiving the values with NSASCIIStringEncoding which could be the cause and I am going to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I am reading my binary portion of data payload directly from packetData variable in iOS application (instead of fullData which is NSString) without converting it first to string and then decoding to byte with UTF8 encoding again.